# Classic ASP page loading twice per request

Tags: asp-classic, session-variables

I have this very straight forward and simple script in classic ASP using **Jscript** as the scripting language:

```js
var counter_value = Session.Contents.Item("counter") || 0;

Response.Write("old:" + counter_value);

Session.Contents("counter") = counter_value + 1;

Response.Write("<br/>");

counter_value = Session.Contents.Item("counter");

Response.Write("new: " + counter_value);
```

When this script is run in the browser for the first time I get this output:

```
old: 0
new: 1
```

But when I refresh the page in the browser, I get an unexpected result:

```
old: 2
new: 3
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that the problem comes from the page being executed twice per request Because of a rule in url-rewrite.

The rule states that all requests should be rewritten to `index.asp`, so when the browser sends a request, the content of `index.asp` gets returned in the response.

The same thing happens again when the browser automatically asks for a `favicon.ico` image.